# belongs_to_many userstamps in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, foreign-keys, associations

Im tryign to update a model of mine so that it will have a created_by and updated_by field. Looking into some questions and answers here, it seems I don't have the same problem as them.

My TestCase model should have a created_by and updated_by foreign key, but it should both be a User class. Is that possible?

something like:

```
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'created_by'
belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'updated_by'
```

Keep in mind that created by and updated_by can be different(meaning another user can edit the testcase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'created_by'
belongs_to :updater, :class_name => "User", :foreign_key => 'updated_by'
```

You should refer to that objects through:

```
item.creator
item.updater
```

Comment: ah there you updated it. was getting an error with the :class. but this works. thanks!